# Windows API error 5: Access is denied error after I install a new font in MikTeX

Tags: miktex, windows

I got the below error:

[image]

After I installed a new font, and update the "miktex-console_admin.exe" I got this error, please suggest how I fix this...

Due to this error, I tried to reinstall, but couldn't succeed, please advise...

Comment: Nobody can tell you what on your computer denies miktex the access--it can be some virus protection, or some company rules, or miktex is trying to write to the wrong place or .... So the first step should not be to reinstall but to try to find some clue what could be going on.

Answer (score 0):

After I removed all the subfolders in `user's` directory, and install the MikTeX in `admin` mode, my problem got solved...